# Convert Date to specific format in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, string, oracle, datetime, oracle11g

I would like to convert the date to this format "2020-08-19" in Oracle SQL.

I did try doing this but it returns as 19-AUG-20

```
SELECT TO_DATE('2020-08-19', 'YYYY-MM-DD') FROM DUAL;
```

OUTPUT

```
19-AUG-20
```

I want the output in the below format:

```
2020-08-19
```

Could anyone please help me with this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why not just use `select '2020-08-19'` if that is what you want?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have a *`date`* that you want to display as a formatted *string*, then use `TO_CHAR()`:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(DATE '2020-08-19', 'YYYY-MM-DD') FROM DUAL;
```

In the function, `DATE '2020-08-19'` is a *literal date*: that's a `date` datatype.

As for your original code:

```
SELECT TO_DATE('2020-08-19', 'YYYY-MM-DD') FROM DUAL;
```

What it does is interpret the input *string* as a *date*, given the format specified as the second argument. This returns a *`date`*, that is then *displayed* according to the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` parameter of your database or session. You can change the parameter value at session level like so:

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'YYYY-MM-DD';
```

Now running the same query gives you the result that you want.

Comment: Thanks @GMB for the quick reply, at the database level when I query the date is stored in the following format ```NLS_DATE_FORMAT DD-MON-RR``` still can I format the date field data to 'YYYY-MM-DD' format? I did try doing that I was getting ```'0071-09-29'```  instead of getting ```'1971-09-29'``` for the date ```29-SEP-71```. I'm not sure how to get the year in YYYY format if it is set to RR at the NLS database level. could you please advise on this? Thanks again!

Comment: @xpetta If you get the value `0071-09-29` then the date has been put into the table incorrectly. If you use `INSERT INTO table_name ( date_column ) VALUES ( TO_DATE( '29-09-71', 'DD-MM-YYYY' ) )` then `71` will be read as `0071` and not `1971`. Changing the NLS settings will not fix this as the data in the table is wrong.

Comment: @xpetta Storage format and display format are two different things. All dates are stored in the same internal 7 byte binary format that is not human-readable (just as a number is stored with no display format). You can display them in any format you like. `nls_date_format` defines the default format for displaying dates, and also for converting strings to dates.